# Undefined Symbol in Kernel Module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, objdump

I am working on a very complex Linux driver. I am moving some files around trying to "cut the fat" a little bit. I have 4 "undefined!" symbols at the linking stage. I have searched my source code and I really don't know where these symbols are getting included.

I thought that if I did an `objdump -DS` on my compiled .ko and searched for the symbols, I might be able to tell from the surrounding decompiled source where they were coming from. But, when I search for the symbols, they aren't even found!

Is there a way to tell WHERE or HOW undefined symbols are getting included?

Comment: Perhaps you might inspect some intermediate Gimple representation of GCC, either passing `-fdump-tree-all` to GCC or using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) ....

Comment: @unexpected62 What are the undefinied symbols?

Comment: The undefined symbols are to my code, nothing Linux generic, so the names aren't relevant. I figured it out though, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a good way to do this.

I used `nm -u` to list the undefined symbols from my object files. (the `.o` files)

[nm - list symbols from object files](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_nm.htm)

Doing that one by one on each `.o` and searching for the symbols I knew were undefined showed me what file they were coming from. Then I had a starting place for finding the symbol in my actual `.c` file, or a header file included from that `.c` file.

Now it's not a needle in a haystack, but rather a needle in a chunk of hay that broke off of the haystack.